# Couchbase: Does publishing views impact access to the bucket?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am running couchbase in production with multi-million docs in my buckets. My code queries views defined on these buckets. Every once in a while I need to add or edit a view.

When I 'publish' the changes, does it affect access to that bucket (in other words: can it still be read and written to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do CRUD operations on that bucket. When you publish the view, in the background it is rebuilding the index for that view/design_doc. Are you seeing something else?

Comment: This is the behavior I am seeing. I could not find this in the docs - and was hoping you'd confirm my assumption. thanks!